# Does an administrator access allow someone to access to the WordPress database?

Tags: admin, mysql

I gave an administrator access to a developper and he made a copy of my entire Wordpress website (meaning : files from my FTP and the whole database).

How did he succeed to do that ?
Does creating an administrator role grant access to the whole FTP and the mysql database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `wp-admin` Administrator access does not grant direct access to files or the database. However, as an Administrator, you can install / activate / use / deactivate / uninstall plugins, and there are a number of plugins which can take backups of the files and the database. So, anything WordPress has access to, they would have access to.